# Removing text before a string

Tags: regex

I have a column that has the following data

> `XS/X / Black`

and I need just the color.

When the column says `S / Black` I'm good, but my regex isn't working when the size is `X/XS`.

To get the size I was using

```
\/.*
```

To get the color I was using

```
^[^/]*/
```

Thoughts on how to identify and remove when it's  `/`  (a space before and after the slash) ?

Comment: What is your regex?

Comment: to get the size I was using
\/.*

Comment: to get the color I was using ^[^/]*/

Comment: But what are the requirements? Try [`^(.*?)\s\/\s(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/07890E/1). Actually, you could just split with `" / "`. Where are you using the regex?

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks. For one column I'm trying to extract just the size so "S" or "XS/S" and for the other column I'm trying to extract just the color so "Black"

Comment: For just the size, you may use `^(.*?)\s\/\s`, for the color, `\s\/\s(.+)`. However, it would be easier to understand what you are doing if you menion how you are using the regex. Is it pandas in Python, or is it splitting columns in R?

Comment: For future reference you should include several samples of values you need to match against. In my answer below I'm making assumptions to try to help you because your question is not very clear.

Comment: What language are using your regex in?

Answer (score 0):

The (\s)* is what you need. This matches zero or more whitespace characters, which I think is what's hanging you up so far.

This should get you on the path, I think...

```
(X+S|S|M|L|X+L)/(\s)*X(\s)*(.+)
```

I've hard coded sizes from XXS to XXL (...actually 1 or more X's, so it will automagically match something like XXXL...). If you have sizes like "3XL" in your data, you'll have to work that out.

The fourth match in the array should be the color.

**Edit:**
This is simpler...

```
.*\s*\/\s*(.+)
```

Your color will be in Group 1, Match 1. 
You can test here.
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
XS/X / Black
```

Pattern ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t0NkcX/2)):

```
/\/ \K.+/
```

Output:

```
Black
```

This pattern avoids using a capture group by using `\K` and will provide the portion of text that follows the slash and space until the end of the string as the full string match.

If you want a capture group, you can use: `/\/ (.+)/`

If you a space after a slash in your sizing values substring then that would change your question and invalidate `slash-space` as a delimiter.

To extend a bit on the realm of possibilities, I believe you should be able to use the following pattern to accurately extract color substrings:

```
[^ ]+$
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
XS/ X / Black                  // Black
XS / X / Black                 // Black
L / XL/XXL / Reddish-Orange    // Reddish-Orange
S /M/ L / Red/White/Blue       // Red/White/Blue
L / XL / Black&White           // Black&White
```